# On integer solutions of $2\sqrt{\sqrt{2x}+\sqrt{y}}=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{2y}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, functions

> $\textsf{Background}$
>
> From the double-angle formula $\cos2\alpha=2\cos^2\alpha-1$, we can get $$\cos15^\circ=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos30^\circ}2}=\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}}2$$ but we also know that it is equivalent to $\dfrac{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}4$.

This is an example of an equality such that $$2\sqrt{\sqrt{2x}+\sqrt{y}}=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{2y}$$ after some rearranging. We can write $y$ in terms of $x$ without much bother: $$y=2+\frac x2+2\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2x}}-\sqrt{2x(1+\sqrt{2x})}.$$ But when are $x$ and $y$ integers? Here is a plot of the curve: [image]

Some obvious solutions are $(0,0)$, $(0,4)$, $(2,3)$ and $(32,0)$. Of course, $x=2k$ for some integer $k$, leaving us with $$y=2+k+2\sqrt{1+2\sqrt k}-2\sqrt{k(1+2\sqrt k)}$$ Hence this boils down to finding $k$ such that $$(1-\sqrt k)\sqrt{1+2\sqrt k}$$ is an integer. Any advances on this?

Comment: I have found $$x=0,y=0;x=0,y=4;x=2,y=3;x=32,y=0$$

Comment: But $$x=0,y=0$$ gives $$0=0$$

Comment: Is there perhaps an error in the equation derived?

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe Not an error in the equation itself, but there is another branch from $(0,0)$ to $(2,3)$. But this is pointless as it is clear that there are no integer solutions in that interval. That's why I haven't put it in.

Comment: After squaring two times a got this here $$-{x}^{4}+16\,{x}^{3}y-2\,{x}^{2}{y}^{2}+16\,x{y}^{3}-{y}^{4}+64\,{x}^{
3}+32\,{x}^{2}y-192\,x{y}^{2}+32\,{y}^{3}-1024\,{x}^{2}+1024\,xy-256\,
{y}^{2}=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

The stated condition leads easily to
$$(\sqrt x + \sqrt{2y} - 2\sqrt2)^2 = 8 - 4\sqrt y.$$
Hence $0 \le y \le 4.$ Trying each value of $y$ in turn, one finds that the only solutions with $x$ also an integer are the four already stated.

Comment: How did you arrive at the above equation?